# How can I allow remote MySQL connection via HTTP/PHP?

Tags: mysql, php, centos7, remote-access

I'm running CentOS 7 on all the servers mentioned below.

I'm testing on a local development environment for setting up separate database and web server.

These servers are two VirtualBox instances connected via Bridged Mode in the local area network so that can see each other without problem.

I want to be able for the WEB server to connect to MySQL on DB server using IP restriction from the WEB server only.

I've read through some discussion threads but none of them help resolve my problem, as many of them are `firewall` or `selinux` related.

I've disabled both `firewalld` and `selinux` so that these are not the factors at the moment.

DB  server IP: 192.168.1.167
WEB server IP: 192.168.1.168

I'm using the following script for test, `http://192.168.1.168/connect.php`

```
<?php
$servername = "192.168.1.167";
$username = "demouser";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

I'm getting `Connection failed: Permission denied` error when performing:

- `wget http://192.168.1.168/connect.php` on the 192.168.1.168 terminal console
- `http://192.168.1.168/connect.php` in my browser windows is also giving me the same error.

(1) However, I am able to successfully connect via command line using `mysql -u demouser -p -h 192.168.1.167` from 192.168.1.168 (WEB server)

(2) I also get `Connected successfully` when directly executing `php connect.php` in the terminal console of 192.168.1.168 (WEB server)

I can only confirm that remote MySQL connection via SSH is working, and via PHP MySQL module is working.

Here's the access privilege on 192.168.1.167 (DB server)

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for demouser@localhost                                                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'demouser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*DB17DD535D122AED147A61C30CD5D01FB3BC5433' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `demodb`.* TO 'demouser'@'localhost'                                                      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for demouser@192.168.1.168                                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'demouser'@'192.168.1.168' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*DB17DD535D122AED147A61C30CD5D01FB3BC5433' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `demodb`.* TO 'demouser'@'192.168.1.168'                                                      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`netstat` on 192.168.1.167 is showing:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2892/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1704/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1053/sshd
```

How can I allow remote MySQL connection via HTTP/PHP, yet only for requests initiating from the aforementioned WEB server?

Comment: Please attach the output on the `getenforce` command.

Comment: `getenforce` currently is showing as `Disabled`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to identify that `SELinux` was the cause of connection failure.

As mentioned in the original thread, I disabled the `SELinux` and Firewall on the **DB** server, which I believed was blocking the remote connection from the **WEB** server.

What is causing the connection issue was `SELinux` on the **WEB** server.

I temporarily disabled it using `setenforce 0` to set it into `permissive` mode.

Everything works.

I re-enabled `SELinux` and Firewall on the **DB** server.  I can still make remote database connection via the PHP script on the **WEB** server.

I can now confirm that the issue was on the **WEB** server initiating the connection.

I re-enabled `SELinux` on the **WEB** server and use the following command to set the boolean for `SELinux` on the **WEB** server.

`setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1`

Currently I'm having `SELinux` active on both **WEB** & **DB** servers in `enforcing` mode, and the remote MySQL connection can still go through successfully.

What I've read on other discussion threads I didn't follow was: which server to configure the `SELinux` booleans.

Hope this thread can help anyone who is experiencing the same problem as I do to save some time.

Comment: `httpd_can_network_connect_db` SELinux boolean must be set on the server where you are running apache.

Comment: I'm running Nginx, and I do require this directive to be turned on as well in order to work.